# Hasselblad: Which lenses mount on which cameras?

Tags: lens, hasselblad

Im interested in the Hasselblad digital system and I would like to know which lenses mount on which cameras. Im especially interested in the H4D and H5D cameras. Which lenses are compatible with these cameras?

Comment: I am getting my popcorn ready just in case “crop factor” comes up.  :)

Comment: What do you mean? Im aware of the „crop factor“ of these large sensors.

Comment: Any time crop factor comes up with APS-C cameras, there is always lots of discussion and mis-understanding. I am just curious to see how it will be when discussing medium format and the “not quite” medium format cameras.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The H4D and H5D take the HC series lenses, or the V-system lenses with an adapter. And to satisfy the "crop factor" popcorn-eaters, there are also HCD lenses which are only appropriate for the smaller-sensor versions of the backs - they're sort of the Hasselblad version of APS-C-only lenses for DSLRs based on 35mm camera systems (like Nikon DX or Canon EF-S lenses). Whether or not you can use the HCD lenses depends on which back your 'Blad has.